# Rails Javascript onchange works with <script> but not externally

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, view, jquery-events

In my `index.html.erb` file I have a form that successfully submits onChange. However, this only works if I use `<script>` tags placed after my form. Why is the same js in `welcome.js` not running? Index loads as a `/welcome` route.

```
# app/assets/javascripts/application.js

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ace.min
//= require jquery.sortable
//= require chartkick
//= require hammer
//= require_tree .
```

External js file

```
# app/assets/javascripts/welcome.js

$('.chart-radio-icon').change(function(){
  $('#mega_form').submit();
});
```

View

```
# views/welcome/index.html.erb
<%= form_tag mega_chart_path, id: 'mega_form', remote: true do %>
    <%= radio_button_tag :metric_type, :followers_count, true, :class => 'chart-radio-icon'%>
    <%= label_tag(:followers, 'Followers', :class => 'chart-label chart-label-social') %>
```

Again, the js works when placed in `<script>` tags in the view, but not externally.

Comment: Is the javascript loaded on the page? Can you get a `console.log('Hello World');` to work?

Comment: @JamesMilani if I put `console.log('Hello World');` in the external file and then go to inspect > console on the page I see nothing.

Comment: Have you restarted your server? This could be related to how your assests are included locally in your pipeline.

Comment: yes, i have restarted the server

Comment: What's going on in your `app/config/initializers/assets.rb`? Do you have anything set in there?

Comment: `Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.1'`
`Rails.application.config.assets.logger = Logger.new($stdout)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Since we've determined that your asset files are not being included in development. For a sanity check try this and restart your server:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile = %w( application.js application.css )
```

**END EDIT**

Since you are using a `require_tree .`, and since the `welcome.js` file is in `app/assets/javascripts`, it will be included on all pages in your application. [See here.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives)
I think that the problem is that on page load, the event listener is not being assigned to the DOM element. Try wrapping your JS code in:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/welcome.js

$(document).ready(function(){
  ....
});
```

Comment: I tried wrapping the existing function, but it did not work

Comment: Can you look at the html of the page and see if the `welcome.js` file is present on the page? It seems like, for some reason, the file's not getting included in assets. What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Upon inspecting the elements of the page and viewing the page source, I could find neither `welcome.js` nor `application.js`. I used ctrl+f and manually inspected the `<head>` in particular

Comment: Our head engineer did not want me to edit that file. I got it working by moving the script to analytics.js, which loads before welcome.js. I did have to wrap it in `$(document).ready` to get it working